# Infinity loop after componentDidUpdate() in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React JS app, which updating boostrap grid table with entries from ASP .NET Core Web API.

And I need to update the grid with new entries after inserting. I did that with help of `componentDidUpdate()` and using `refreshList()` function there, but I am getting an infinity loop of `refreshList()` function.

[image]

Any thoughts about how to update the grid without that loop?

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Table, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Button, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';

import {AddDepModal} from './AddDepModal';
import {EditDepModal} from './EditDepModal';

export class Department extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {deps:[], addModalShow: false, editModalShow: false}
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.refreshList();
    }
    refreshList()
    {
       fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/departments")
       .then(response=> response.json())
       .then(data=> { 
        this.setState({deps:data});
       });
    }

    componentDidUpdate()
    {
        this.refreshList();
    }

    render(){

     const {deps, depid, depname} = this.state;
     let addModalClose = () => this.setState({addModalShow:false})
     let editModalClose = () => this.setState({editModalShow:false})
    return (
        <div>
     <Table className = "mt-4" striped bordered hover size ="sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DepartmentID</th>
            <th>DepartmentName</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {deps.map(dep=> 
            <tr key = {dep.id}> 
            <td>{dep.id}</td>
            <td>{dep.name}</td>
            <td>
                <ButtonToolbar>
                    <Button
                    className ="mr-2" variant ="info"
                    onClick = {() => this.setState({editModalShow:true, depid: dep.id, depname: dep.name})}
                    >
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                    <EditDepModal
                    show = {this.state.editModalShow}
                    onHide = {editModalClose}
                    depid = {depid}
                    depname = {depname}/>
                </ButtonToolbar>
            </td>
            </tr>
            )}
    </tbody>
     </Table>
     <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button variant = "primary" onClick = {() => this.setState({addModalShow: true})}>Add Department</Button>
    <AddDepModal 
    show ={this.state.addModalShow} 
    onHide ={addModalClose}/>
</ButtonToolbar>
</div>
    )
    }
}
```

Comment: How and Where did you do the inserting action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove componentDidUpdate() because refreshData doesn't depend from props to fetch data and there aren't any checks with prevProps and newProps.

You can call refreshData method from Add or Save Button callback.

I image that you are saving data from modal code, add setState callback.

Modal save data, onhide set show state to false and call refreshData from once.

let addModalClose = () => this.setState({addModalShow:false}, this.refreshData)

Comment: I can't use it. Not too many experience with JavaScript. Can you help Please?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding second function to addModalClose worked as needed!

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `this.refreshList();` which does some thing and then set the state. After the state is set, `render` functions is called and in turn `componentDidUpdate` is called again, setting the infinite loop. To make it work, compare from the previous `props` and then call the `this.refreshList();`  if needed.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.depid !== prevProps.depid) { //Replace `depid` with the props you like to compare changes. If that is changed, then only call
    this.refreshList();
  }
}
```

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note
>   that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or
>   you’ll cause an infinite loop. It would also cause an extra
>   re-rendering which, while not visible to the user, can affect the
>   component performance. If you’re trying to “mirror” some state to a
>   prop coming from above, consider using the prop directly instead. Read
>   more about why copying props into state causes bugs.

see the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Can't figure how to solve it.. Can you help please?

Comment: @hoozr Updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: doesn't work. Still no updating, but no loop as well.

Comment: Yes, but without componentDidUpdate. As I understood, I don't make any state changes, so I don't need it. Was better to add refresh function with closing modal window function.

Comment: cool. Yeah most often you do not require to use `componentDidUpdate` . So whenever you see that, first get completely sure whether it's required. And if it is, make sure it's wrapped under a condition so it doesn't go in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling `refreshList` in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. As described in the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

you should at some condition to avoid an infinity loop in componentDidUpdate.

Comment: how should I make condition?